# Storing appended excel to specific folder

Tags: python, excel, pandas, append

I have appended multiple excel files and I want to store it in a specific folder. How can I specify the file path where it can be stored. I used the following code:

```
# importing the required modules
import glob
import pandas as pd

# specifying the path to excel files
path = "C:\file path"
 
# xlsx files in the path
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
 
# list of excel files we want to merge.
# pd.read_excel(file_path) reads the 
# excel data into pandas dataframe.
excl_list = []
 
for file in file_list:
    excl_list.append(pd.read_excel(file))
 
# concatenate all DataFrames in the list
# into a single DataFrame, returns new
# DataFrame.
excl_merged = pd.concat(excl_list, ignore_index=True)
 
# exports the dataframe into excel file
# with specified name.
excl_merged.to_excel('combined_files.xlsx', index=False)
```

I have a serial number column. File 1 has S/N 1-10 and File 2 has S/N 1-5. When we append, the combined file has S/N 1-10, then 1-5 and not 1-15. How can I make my S/N 1-15?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the full path in `excl_merged.to_excel()`. eg.:

```
excl_merged.to_excel(r'C:\file path\output_dir\combined_files.xlsx', index=False)
```

To create a new column 'S/N' from the index, you could do something like:

```
excl_merged.reset_index(inplace=True)
excl_merged.drop(['index', 'S/N'], axis=1, inplace=True)
excl_merged['S/N'] = excl_merged.index
excl_merged.to_excel(r'C:\file path\output_dir\combined_files.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But the serial number column of my files are 1,2,...,10 and 1,2,..,5. when I append it, it comes out to be 1,2,...10,1,2,..,5. Is it possible to get the serial numbers to be 1,2,...,15?

Comment: What do you mean by "serial number column"? Can you add a sample of the data in the question and what you would want it to look like in the merged excel?

Comment: Is there a logic to the serial number column, any specific way you want to update it? Or do you just need a column with a unique number? In the last case, you can just reset the index and use/rename that to your S/N column...

Comment: The serial number column helps to check the count in the excel. so it should read from 1-15 and not display the combined excel's 1-10 and then 1-5. How can we do that by resetting the index? Can you help?

Comment: See the edit. Does this work for what you want?